# Umlauts with parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop

I have a Windows 11 virtual machine with Parallels with a standard US apple keyboard.

I do I manage to type umlauts in the Windows VM? (similarly to <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by the letter on macOS)

Comment: Just a comment since I don't use Parallels, but you may need to solve this in Windows itself. For example using [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose). It's not using the same key combinations you're used to on macOS, instead it's using the X Window (Linux, Unix) combinations which also allow you to input next to any diacritics. (I use it on my German Window PC with a US keyboard layout.)

Comment: @DarkDust: Parallels installs a special Keyboard (US (Apple)) so I supposed that the installed Parallel tools would be able to do the mapping. As far as I remember it works with VMware fusion.

Comment: Windows just ain't that smart I'm afraid. The 'special' Parallels key layouts give you a shed-load more things you can type by using Right Alt [which it maps as AltGr] but the only way I know of to add umlauts etc is to use one of the International layouts. I've been testing this on Parallels & I cannot get the umlaut to work. It used to work when I remoted into a PC, but not in Parallels. Test ` then e, or ' then e & that works. Shift ' [ie "]then u does not work for me, on either British Parallels, US Parallels or the built-in MS US International [which should work].

Comment: This is how it *should* work, using an Inernational layout - https://superuser.com/questions/1142924/umlaut-ä-ö-ü-on-english-us-layout